# Java MySQL updating rows when deleting a row

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database with a AUTO_INCREMENTING id column and a name column. If I delete a row from the data I would like to update all of the other rows id so the sequence is right again, I am very lost please help me.

I tried this:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM " + table_name_products);
        int count = 0;
        while(rs.next()){
            count = rs.getInt("COUNT(id)");
        }

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
            if(i > id){
                stmt.addBatch("UPDATE " + table_name_products + " SET id = "+ i-- +" WHERE id = "+ i +";");
            }
        }
```

Comment: i don't think it's possible

Comment: you are not supposed to change id, of a row after it is created. just ignore the gaps :-) or have a `deleted` boolean column to be by default false and true when logically row is deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much Subin that is an awesome idea, will be doing that thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

I think the only solution would be to cache all rows after the one you are deleting some place, delete those rows, then add the cached rows to the table again.

There might be database management command to do this, but you wouldn't want to be doing it after every delete.

Comment: Well this isnt a very much occuring thing so since this program will only be lightly used

Answer (score 0):

What about a database [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).

> A database trigger is procedural code that is automatically executed
>   in response to certain events on a particular table or view in a
>   database.